# mvn release:perform creates multiple staging repos

Tags: maven

I have a project that uses maven and I am attempting to deploy to the sonatype OSS repository. When I execute mvn release:perform, 5 different staging repos are created instead of just one. The various files are spread among these different repos so I cannot successfully deploy.

Is there a reason that maven is splitting up my release?

The project along with my pom files are here:
https://github.com/Uncodin/bypass/tree/master/platform/android

[image: sonatype repos]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that each staging repository thought that it was deployed from a different IP address. This can happen in corporate environments where a floating IP address proxies outbound requests.

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-5454?focusedCommentId=180666&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-180666

Answer (score 0):

the parent you are using (https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/central/content/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.pom) does not really give a hint on whats going wrong. there is only one release repository configured: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/

Is it possible this is caused by some configuration inside the Nexus Proxy? And not by your maven structure?

Comment: Maybe repository isn't the right term. All the bundles get sent to the same repo as far as I can tell. I've attached a screenshot from the nexus